# PWA. How to make an offer to the user to install the application?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I can of course force install my pwa on the device. However, existing sites on the market themselves offer the user to install the application. And about the possibility to install my application, the user will not know if he does not want to try (most likely he will not want to).

How to make the user such an offer, I unfortunately have not yet figured out. Articles could not be found (perhaps incorrectly set the search), the analysis of the code of service workers also did not help.

Help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Chrome mobile, the default prompt is very visible. On desktop, less so.

But, Chrome actually has an event for this. If everything is in order for a PWA to be installed, the 'beforeinstallprompt' event is fired. You can simply add a listener to this event, and use that to display a message on your page to inform the user of the possibility to install the PWA.

The following example is written for Angular, but you can get the idea of the event.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    /**
     * The beforeinstallprompt event is only triggered in certain browsers. This event simply indicates that everything is in order
     * for the user to install the PWA. On mobile Chrome, a message is shown by default to the user, but we can also interfere and
     * block it. This way, we can show our own message, and continue the event on our own terms.
     * In this case, we store the event, and prevent it from continuing. We then show a regular <div> in the HTML, which contains the
     * question to install the PWA, and a button to do so. That button then triggers the prompt, which the user can then accept or deny.
     * The result of this prompt is mostly irrelevant to the functionality. Our code has no impact on the proceedings of the installation
     * after the user has accepted the prompt.
     * A possible usecase for the Promise resolved by the prompt, is for metrics. We can use the result to calculate how many users have
     * accepted or denied our prompts.
     */
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
      // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
      e.preventDefault();
      // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
      this.deferredPrompt = e;

      console.log('beforeinstallprompt!');
      // if askedOnce is true, no need to ask again.
      this.showPwaPrompt = !this.askedOnce;
    });
  }

  acceptPwaPrompt() {
    this.showPwaPrompt = false;
    this.askedOnce = true;
    this.deferredPrompt.prompt();  // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
    this.deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
      if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
      } else {
        console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
      }

      this.deferredPrompt = null;
    });
  }
```